# UNIQUE constraint failed in sqlalchemy when trying to update database

Tags: sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms

I keep getting UNIQUE constraint failed when trying to update data in my database. I am using username as the primary_key, but this code works just fine when I construct an object and add it to the database in the terminal. It is only when I try it in my views.py that I have issues.

Here is the error

```
IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: mobility.username [SQL: u'INSERT INTO mobility (username, cc_letter, sabc_cbt) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: (u'pass', u'tt', None)]

File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/app/views.py", line 57, in mobility_edit_user

  db.session.commit()
```

views.py - this is the one causing issue at db.session.commit()

```
@app.route('/mobility_edit_user', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def mobility_edit_user():
    #build user list
    data=User.query.with_entities(User.username).all()
    users=[]
    for i in data:
        users.append(i[0])
    form=MobilityForm(request.form)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form['submit']=='SelectUser':
            #moves selected user to front of form to persist with next call
            users.insert(0, users.pop(users.index(request.form.get('user'))))
            data=Mobility.query.filter_by(username=request.form.get('user')).first()
            #form.populate_obj(data)
            form=MobilityForm(obj=data)
            flash("Selected User " + request.form.get('user'))
        elif request.form['submit']=='Update' and form.validate():
            print("validated")
            u=Mobility()
            form.populate_obj(u)
            u.username=request.form.get('user')
            db.session.add(u)
            print("added")
            db.session.commit()
            flash("Updated User" + request.form.get('user'))
        else:
            #move selected user to front of form
            users.insert(0, users.pop(users.index(request.form.get('user'))))
            data=Mobility.query.filter_by(username=request.form.get('user')).first()
            form=MobilityForm(obj=data)
            flash("Form not validated")
    elif request.method == "GET":
        form=MobilityForm(request.form)
        flash("GET")
    return render_template('mobility_edit_user.html',title='Mobility Edit User', 
        form=form, users=users)
```

models.py

```
class MobilityForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Mobility
```

forms.py

```
class MobilityForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Mobility
```

mobility_edit_users.html

```
<!-- extend base layout -->
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
    {% include 'flash.html' %}
    <div class="well">
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" name="edit">
            <div class="control-group">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="SelectUser">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <select name="user">
                    {% for user in users %}<option value={{ user }}>{{ user }}</option>{% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
            <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" width="100%" style="background color:white">
            {% for attr, value in form._fields.iteritems() %}
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ attr }}</th>
                    <td>{{ value }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </table> 
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```